# Check parameter key name or object key within JSTL loop, e.g. .hasOwnProperty

Tags: jsp, jstl

This is a bit of an academic question because I have a solution, sort of, below, but I'm curious if there's a way to do this.

I'm a bit green with JSTL but so far it seems pretty straight forward.  I have an object on my .jsp courtesy of Spring MVC which contains a `List<Map<String,Object>>` like:

```
typea : value1
typea : value2
typeb : value3
typeb : value4
...
```

The objects of *typea* will go in one html select control as options and objects of *typeb* will go in a second html select control.

What I had looked like this:

```
<c:if test="${!empty objectlist}">
    <c:if test="${!empty objectlist['typea']">
        <c:forEach items="${objectlist['typea']}" var="typeval">
            <option value="<c:out value="${typeval}"/>">
                <c:out value="${typeval}" />            
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</c:if>
```

I got an error with this approach: Java.lang.NumberFormatException: for input string: "typea".

I also tried testing for *objectlist.typea*, which produced no error but also no output.

And, I also tried just relying on the truthy state of an expression like *object.typea* without testing for it, expecting that setting *items* to *object.typea* would quietly work for assigning *typeval* and ignore *typeb* instances in the list.  But it didn't, it just produced the same above error.

I've looked through a lot of JSTL examples for handling loops and variable scopes but haven't seen anything like .hasOwnProperty for JSTL.

**Solution (of sorts)**

Presently, I've solved the issue by breaking the object into two different list objects for the specific purposes.  It was mushed together to support an Android app that also uses this same application, so I didn't want to mess with what was already there.

The JSTL now looks like:

```
<c:if test="${!empty objectlist}">
    <c:forEach items="${objectlist}" var="typevar">                                     
        <option value="<c:out value="${typevar.typea}"/>">
        <c:out value="${typevar.typea}" />                                      
    </c:forEach>                                    
</c:if>
```

It would be interesting to see how to do an equivalent .hasOwnProperty check with JSTL, if such a thing is possible.  I'd much rather do this the right way than just "what works".

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Are you saying my view expects Map<String, List<Object>> because of the way I have tried to use JSTL or is that the standard output when adding calling addObject from ModelAndView under SpringMVC?  At the moment, the controller has something like ModelAndView.addObject(Map<List<String,Object>>, so I was expecting 'typea' in the place of String for the relevant list items.

Comment: Ah, no. I certainly can not.  So my underlying problem is I didn't understand how the java object was being mapped.  My working solution works because it follows the structure of what is delivered to the jsp.